# Cryptopp in multi-threaded DLL, VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, crypto++

I'm trying to use Cryptopp 5.6.2 on XPSP3 using VS 2010. New to this...

I need to use the mult-threading DLLs as that is what my application uses, so I changed all references in the Crypto++ project properties from `/MT[d]` to `/MD[d]`. All Crypto++ seems to build OK.

However, all is not happy with my C++ console app - I have the standard `GetNewAndDeleteForCryptoPP` and that seems to be called OK (remove it and cryptopp gives an error, include it and cryptopp doesn't print warnings).

All seems fine until I add in the line `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA256>`. It compiles fine but causes two LNK2001 errors for unresolved symbols for `CryptoPP::ThreadUserTimer::GetCurrentTimerValue(void)` and
`CryptoPP::ThreadUserTimer::TicksPerSecond(void)`.

Running out of ideas here - I can't paste the code due to arcane rules at the place I work, however I have included `dll.h`, `cryptlib.h`, `osrng.h`, `aes.h`, `sha.h`, `hex.h`, `integer.h`, `modes.h` and `pwdbased.h`.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue too, it doesn't look like that class is being exported. Adding `CRYPTOPP_DLL` to the declaration of `ThreadUserTimer` in `hrtimer.h` will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[user1520427](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1520427/user1520427) provided you the answer. You need to add `CRYPTOPP_DLL` for a few classes and functions.

`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA256>` is a header only implementation, so it does not need  `CRYPTOPP_DLL`. See [pwdbased.h](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/pwdbased_8h_source.html).

However, `ThreadUserTimer` is *not* header only, so you need to modify [`hrtimer.h`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/hrtimer_8h_source.html):

OLD:

```
00042 class ThreadUserTimer : public TimerBase
00043 {
00044    ...
00048 };
```

NEW:

```
00042 class CRYPTOPP_DLL ThreadUserTimer : public TimerBase
00043 {
00044     ...
00048 };
```